# Creating an MKPolygon from the intersection of 2 or more MKPolygon objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

Does anyone know if this is possible.  I'm trying to create a pretty complex polygon, and was wondering if there's any way to take 2 or more objects that are MKPolygon's and create a new MKPolygon from it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MKPolygon and it's ancestors are pretty simplistic. About the most you can do with ease is to make a large mkpolygon and start filling in inner polygon "holes" or rings to create more complex shapes.

That being said, if you're talking about real geometric math, unions, intersections, and more complex functions, you may want to use a geo-specific framework (or treat your lat/long as x/y double floats and just use regular textbook geometry functions to build 2d polys)

Michael Weisman has a good geo/GIS lib called [ShapeKit](http://Www.GitHub.com/mweisman/shapekit), geared towards iOS specifically. It acts as a front end to GEOS and PROJ.4, two extremely powerful libraries. This is probably your best, safest bet.

Another option that you may want to explore, if you don't have to compute the polygons on the device, ... Serve up your polygons from a GIS powered database server. I have a few modifications to shapekit that let you import binary WKB polygons from mysql or elsewhere ... You've got fast powerful functions there to offload processing power if needed. Or you could even bring them straight from a Esri shapefile to iOS if that's where your coming from... I did a [proof of concept](http://www.GitHub.com/grgcombs/iOS-shapefile) of that on GitHub too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I've never worked w/ any of those technologies though, so I'm a little hesitant to go down this path.  I'm actually getting hurricane data from a flat text file of latitude and longitude  points and trying to recreate the margin of error cone.  My algorithm to generate the cone works well, unless one of the projection points involves a heading that goes back toward the previous location.  Then my Polygon gets all tangled.

Comment: I was hoping to actually draw some MKCircle objects with a margin of error radius, and draw the cone that get's tangled up, and then take the intersection of those objects to create a new polygon that would be much more accurate.

Comment: Instead of plotting it out point by point (if I understand the tangledness) perhaps look for a way to wrap a triangle around the area ... Like a three sided bounding box, checking for min/max coords.  Alternatively, do some simplification of the points ... Either find a Dickie implementation or for every three points, average the middle one. That'll speed up rendering too.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a solution for this. Check out [MKPolygon-GPC](https://github.com/SunGard-Labs/MKPolygon-GPC). Its an Objective-C wrapper around Alan's the GPC lib.